# How to install x-cache on max os?

Tags: php, macos, caching, osx-yosemite, xcache

I have installed already php 5.6 and memcached using http://php-osx.liip.ch/. Now I need x-cache and I don't know how to install and turn module on for php. Please, help. Thank's in advance.

Comment: First step is reading documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you installed [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/), fire up a Terminal and run `brew install php56-xcache`. You might need to run `brew tap homebrew/dupes && brew tap homebrew/versions && brew tap homebrew/homebrew-php` before you're able to run it.

Also, Homebrew will probably install a new version of PHP 5.6, but it's seriously worth it as easy as a `brew install php56-mcrypt` if you wanted to install mcrypt (or any other package).